# What's the differens between unlinking and removing a GPO?

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

Yesterday I was altering an automated installscript in order to remove a faulty package during client installation. All installation packages are linked to a certain "installation OU". I unlinked but didn't delete the link and it produced some strange results. It appeared that the script included said package but didn't execute it and this caused a great mess.

I thought unlinking a GPO would "deactivate" it but obviously I was wrong, so what is the real differens between unlinking and removing the link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you delete a GPO it's gone. When you unlink it the GPO is still there but no longer applies to the object you unlinked it from. If you get odd results you should run the RSOP tool, which will tell you just what policies are applied. Be aware that some policies remain in place even after the GPO which caused them is no longer active. e.g. Policies that applied registry changes.